# Zooming in makes div hover over fixed-position img

Tags: html, css

I have a header which has an `img` for the logo (`position: fixed`) and a `grid` which is centered using margins, which contains whatever except for the logo is in the header.  The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='header'>
    <img id='logo' src='http://i65.tinypic.com/dw2nw9.png'>
    <div id='header-grid'>
        <div id='item-one'></div>
        <div id='item-two'></div>
        <div id='item-three'></div>
        <div id='item-four'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--header-height);
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    z-index: 3141592;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 100px; 
    max-height: var(--header-height);
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#header-grid {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: var(--header-height);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

Now, when I zoom in, the `#header-grid` goes over the `#logo`.   I want them to stay next to each other instead of one going on top of the other

Comment: Do you need to use grid for this? Can you use flex box or inline block?

Comment: @Pete screen width is 100%.  The header-grid is smaller than the header itself, and it goes in the middle.  That's what has the 900px width.  Also, positioning it because if I don't, I can't use margin for centering header-grid.  I find it easier with margins.

Comment: yeah that's not the question - what do you want the logo to do in smaller screens? obviously whenever the screen is smaller than the logo plus the grid, the logo is going to overlap so what do you want it to do if you don't want it to overlap?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu It's very very easier with grid for me.  I also don't really know how to use flexbox.

Comment: @Pete I want the header-grid to be next to the logo (even if it doesn't show in its entirety) instead of going over the logo.  I can change the logo from position:fixed if needed.  Centering the header-grid is gonna be a bit harder in that case.

Comment: @Pete Would making the logo position:relative and display:inline work?  Then I'd have to center the header-grid, but I don't know how to.

Comment: @Pete Err, alright.  I'll probably try your way if nothing else comes up.  I'd have to learn a lot more though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a grid solution for you:

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  z-index: 3141592;
  display: grid;
  
  /* add the following */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, auto) 1fr;  /* not sure about grid but you need the repeat so the second column can be centred */
  justify-items: center;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: var(--header-height);
  margin-left: 10px; /* change this to margin as you shouldn't add padding to images */
  
  margin-right: auto;   /* add this to push to the left */
}

#header-grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  
  grid-column-start: 2;  /* add this so it sits in centre */
  
  /* for demo */
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'>
  <img id='logo' src='http://i65.tinypic.com/dw2nw9.png'>
  <div id='header-grid'>
    <div id='item-one'></div>
    <div id='item-two'></div>
    <div id='item-three'></div>
    <div id='item-four'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```